# how to check if player stands on platform?

Tags: platformer

I want to test if player stands on platform.

I have 32x32 platform sprites.

My code looks like

```
   for (block in blocks) {
    if (collides(playerX, playerY - 7, block.blockX, block.blockY)) {
     fall = true;
    }
  }
```

but it is works wrong.
My player sometimes fall while walking on other platforms.
my collision function works well but maybe 7 is not enough or too much.

Comment: What are you using to program this? If this is an issue with your code, it should be migrated to Stack overflow.

Comment: There is no problems with code, I think. I use C++ and SFML. Collision detection works well but I don't know how to properly test this.

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry Please note that this community is also for fixing code, as long as its related to video games, and collision falls into this category. Stack overflow is for non-game related code.

Comment: @TomTsagk I didn't know that. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: Can you show us your `collides` function?